# Browser default font loads instead of fallback font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm struggling to get my fallback font to load properly.  I've got arial dialed in as a fallback font with the help of the new ascent-override, descent-override, and size-adjust properties.

But when the page loads, instead of it being Arial that loads, then my web font, I'm seeing the browser default (in this case) serif font.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: local('Lato'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://my-media-server-url.com/static-4/webfont/lato/Lato-Regular.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato-Fallback-Arial";
    src: local("Arial");
    ascent-override: 101.3181%;
    descent-override: 21.865%;
    size-adjust: 97.4159%;
}

h1.main__title {
  font-family: Lato, Lato-Fallback-Arial, sans-serif;
}

.main__title {
  font-size: var(--text-4xl);
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

And the relevant HTML is just an `<h1 class="main__title">Story title here</h1>`

I expect the page to load with Arial for the font in the h1 tag and then swap out with Lato once that loads.

I actually see the default serif font as per the browser's default for an h1 tag, then Lato loads, and it appears the Arial is never used at all.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Insight appreciated :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Works flawlessly on Firefox and chrome - also emulating a throttled network. Which browser are you're using? See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/gOELBxw)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It is not possible, the fallback font gets used if the request for the "normal" font can not be completed. So if the font can't be found or the request times out.

So the browser uses its default font and then when Lato is loaded, switches to lato. It is not able to use a different font while loading.

Comment: Makes no difference.  I've done it with quotes and without.  Same problem either way.  But thank you!

Comment: I did some research and edited the Answer. The behaviour you want is not possible. I mean you could try setting the font of the Text to Arial using css and then load the font via Javascript and change it if it was loaded but that might be too complicated for a simple Font.